# GMAIL API Service Account - Validate a user

Tags: gmail-api

When using Service Account to get domain wide access, is it possible to validate if the user is a valid user in the domain for which the Service Account is trying to access the data?

Comment: I didn't understand your use case clearly. So, do you want to check whether  users in the domain or valid or not? If this is the case, i don't think there can be invalid users in the domain. When service account wants to access data of user in domain, for the first time, user should allow you and provide their details where google validates user details to check whether they are valid or not. If user details are not correct, then google will throw an error. Let me know if you usecase is different.

Comment: Basically, in my application, before I try to fetch a user's data, I want to verify if the configured user is correct so that I can validate any misconfiguration

Answer (score 0):

Use the Admin SDK Directory API [users.get()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/get) request against the admin user who installed your app and the user in question. If the value of the customerId attribute is the same for both users, they're in the same Google Apps instance. If its not or if you get an error on the user in question, they're not.

Comment: I want to use the service account and b able to verify if the configured user is a valid one